# Как изменять значение элемента списка Qlist?

Tags: c++, qt

Например, есть вот такой список:

```
Qlist<int> int_list;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   int_list.push_back(i);
}
```

После того как он сформировался, я хочу изменить значение второго элемента на 5, есть ли возможность это сделать без `removeAt()` и `insert()`?

Comment: С qt не знаком, но в документации сказано что есть доступ по индексу http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#operator-5b-5d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь оператором `[]`

```
int_list[2] = 5;
```

Comment: Только вот [2] даст третий элемент.

Comment: @alexolut, это философский вопрос. Там где вы видите первый, второй и третий элемент, я вижу нулевой, первый и второй =)

Comment: нулевой может быть индекс (смещение), но не элемент.